# how to create pagination to change html in laravel

Tags: laravel, pagination

```
 <div class="row clearfix">
            @foreach($distric->area_list as $area_list)

               @foreach($area_list->directory as $directory)
               @foreach($directory->dir_category_sub_set as $dir_category_sub_set)
               @if($dir_category_sub_set->sub_category_id == '557057')

                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                  <div class="single-product">
                    <figure>
                      <img src="/img/content/post-img-12.jpg" alt="">

                      <div class="rating">
                        <ul class="list-inline">
                          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i></a></li>
                          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>

                        <p>Featured</p>

                      </div> <!-- end .rating -->

                      <figcaption>
                        <div class="bookmark">
                          <a href="https://hanuma.lk/{{$directory->field_link}}"><i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i> Bookmark</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="read-more">
                          <a href="https://hanuma.lk/{{$directory->field_link}}"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Read More</a>
                        </div>

                      </figcaption>
                    </figure>

                    <h4><a href="https://hanuma.lk/{{$directory->field_link}}">{{$directory->name_of_the_business_place}}</a></h4>

                    <h5><a href="https://hanuma.lk/{{$directory->field_link}}">{{$directory->address_no_of_the_business_place}},{{$directory->address_street_of_the_business_place}}</a>, <a href="/land/{{$directory->directory_id}}">{{$area_list->name}},{{$distric->name}}</a></h5>

                    <p>T.P:
                      @if($directory->phone_of_the_business_place>0)
                      {{$directory->phone_of_the_business_place}}/
                      @endif

                      {{$directory->mobile_of_the_business_place}} <br> {{$directory->created_date}}</p>

                    <a class="read-more" href="https://hanuma.lk/{{$directory->field_link}}"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Read More</a>

                  </div> <!-- end .single-product -->
                </div> <!-- end .grid-layout -->
                @endif  
                  @endforeach
                  @endforeach
                  @endforeach
```

I have this code and I want to create pagination to this how to do this can I do this without any page refreshing? I can not use laravel pagination method because I do not get data from database directly

I searched different methods to add pagination but I could not fined a suitable method for my project

Comment: do you mean the user stays on the page without refreshing while navigating ?, if so you need js, also at some point you need to use the `paginate()` method, no way around this

Comment: I can not use paginate() because I'm not getting data from my directory table directly I'm directly getting data from my districts table only

Comment: if `directory` table is a relation then you need to include it before paginating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has provided paginate method that you can use [laravel pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#introduction)

you only need to retrieve the data and add the method like:

```
$documents = District::find($id)->area_list()->directory()->get();
return response()->json($documents);
```

and show the link of pagination in your view like:

```
{{$documents->links()}}
@foreach($documents as $document)
    {{$document->name}}
@endforeach
```

finish, this is the example how to use pagination.

Comment: in my controller I getting data from only this table $districs = district::all();

Comment: okay lets change the document into district.. but what data will you want to paginate?

Comment: I want to paginate $directory data

Comment: can you screen shoot how is your page?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DC1e8mdDM1qq1m3VykrBC6eYjzVYicMl?usp=sharing  I uploaded screenshot to this thank you

Comment: do you want to get the specific district `district::find($id)` or you want to get all district?

Comment: I want to get the specific district and after that I want to display all the directory in that dictrict

Comment: I have editted my answer. let's try it again and tell me what will display

Comment: It will give a error "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::directory()"

Comment: how if you delete the `()`

Comment: now get this one "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$directory"

Comment: check My answer, I have editted.. let's see what is the response